# Why Template parameter is Interface but I am asked anyway to use "default(I)"?

Tags: c#, templates, unity-game-engine, interface

I think it is a bit strange, I want "I" to be only a interface type, and T being a class implenenting that interface type (or extending it).

Seems either I'm unable to set "null" value or to force correctly to just restrict the template to interface type.

```
public class MyClass< T, I> where T: I
{
    private I myInterface = null; // error here. I have to use "default(I)"
}
```

Am I forcing correctly to have I "interface" ? otherwise why should I have to use "default(I)"?

The reason to use I is because T has overloaded null check operator (I'm using Unity3D and hence I have to check equality over interface to avoid a bottleneck.

Well in reality I have:

```
public class MyClass< T, I>: MonoBehaviour, where T: MonoBehaviour, I
{
    private I myInterface = null; // error here. I have to use "default(I)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the code below is a valid implementation to your generic type parameters, you can't be 100% sure `T` is a class (the only type being nullable):

```
MyClass<int, IEquatable<int>> m;
```

However, using the `class` constraint, it is:

```
public class MyClass<T, I> where T: I where I : class
{
    private I myInterface = null; // <-- now it is valid
}
```

Comment: `where I: class did the trick` ! thanks you :), and very concise and usefull explaination